# Wso2esb service proxy put in jms queue and sends back 200OK

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

i really spent a lot of time without any success.
I'am trying to make this scenario :

Client calls -> ESB service proxy -> JMS -> send 200OK back to the client

I have used thouse properties :

But my client receives 202 accepted http status.

Is there a property like the "FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" to send back 200 instead of 202.

I have tried using this one but not working :-\ :

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: post your proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

No property to send back '200', but you can simply create your own response with payloadFactory and send it back :

```
 <payloadFactory>
    <format>
       <myResponse/>
    </format>
    <args/>
 </payloadFactory>
 <header name="To" action="remove"/>
 <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
 <send/>
```